# How to call device function inside an object from CUDA kernel in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, cuda, numba

I am writing very specific Neural Network and I have many classes of different activation functions, each has function for normal python and one jitted as device function. The problem is calling that method from inside a CUDA kernel.

```
@cuda.jit(device=True)
def activation_fn(z):
    return max(0, z)

@cuda.jit
def backprop_kernel(arr):
    arr[cuda.threadIdx.x] = activation_fn(arr[cuda.threadIdx.x])

def backprop_GPU(x, y):
    arr = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
    print(arr)
    backprop_kernel[1, 7](arr)
    print(arr)

backprop_GPU(None, None)
```

This works perfectly fine but I want to make the code bellow work.

```
class Activation:
    
    @cuda.jit(device=True)
    def fn(z):
        return max(0, z)

class Network:

    def __init__(self):
        self.activation_fn = Activation()
    
    @cuda.jit
    def kernel(arr):
        arr[cuda.threadIdx.x] = activation_fn(arr[cuda.threadIdx.x])

    def backprop(self, x, y):
        arr = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
        self.kernel[1, 7](arr)

net = Network()
net.backprop(None, None)
```

How do I make the "activation_fn" accesible from the kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@cuda.jit` has to be used with functions, not members, so you need to define the decorated functions inside methods, and capture the activation function when you define the kernel:

```py
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np


class Activation:
    def __init__(self):
        @cuda.jit(device=True)
        def fn(z):
            return max(0, z)

        self.fn = fn


class Network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.activation = Activation()

        activation_fn = self.activation.fn

        @cuda.jit
        def kernel(arr):
            arr[cuda.threadIdx.x] = activation_fn(arr[cuda.threadIdx.x])

        self.kernel = kernel

    def backprop(self, x, y):
        arr = np.array([-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3])
        self.kernel[1, 7](arr)
        print(arr)


net = Network()
net.backprop(None, None)
```

prints:

```
$ python repro.py 
[0 0 0 0 1 2 3]
```

(Note, I omitted the performance warnings that come out here, as they're orthogonal to the issue at hand)